# How to retain the session even after the browser is closed? I am using open id connect based authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, session-cookies, progressive-web-apps, openid-connect

After successful login using Open ID connect(Using OIDC client js), I can see a cookie getting created which retains the session. Once the browser is closed, the cookie and the iframe (which checks the session) will be removed and I will have to login again. Mine is a pwa which is used in mobile devices. How can I retain the session even after the app is closed. Someone please guide me!